# AWS Java putObject InvalidRedirectLocation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

When I try to upload a file to s3 using the aws java sdk I get an error about InvalidRedirectLocation.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
The website redirect location must have a prefix of 'http://' or 'https://' or '/'. 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRedirectLocation; 
Request ID: E801AFDA2A22A20E; S3 Extended Request ID: AAlLOlndWp2dAAA56Vlxs+ZTLCK/
HHaPv/ySaqjIAAAO4wv8qzkm17A7o7YOrtmOx4YJO+yfAAA=), S3 Extended Request ID: LAlAO
lndAp2dAAPA6Vlxs+ZTLCK/AAaPv/ySaqjIAAAO4wv8qzkm17b7o7AOrtmOx4AAO+yflAA=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1302)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4330)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4277)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1750)
    at awsTest.main(awsTest.java:67)
```

Here is a snippet from my code.

```
String s3Bucket = "test_bucket";
String s3FileName = "test_file.txt";
String localFileName = "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\test_file.txt";    

s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(s3Bucket, s3FileName, localFileName));
```

I am able to list files in a bucket and copy files from one bucket to another, but I am not able upload files. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was passing the location of the file as a string to the putObject function, I needed to use the File Class so the following code solved my issue.

```
String s3Bucket = "test_bucket";
String s3FileName = "test_file.txt";
String localFileName = "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\test_file.txt";    
File file = new File(localFileName);

s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(s3Bucket, s3FileName, file ));
```

Comment: The error message seems confusing, but the cause is that when the third argument for a new [`PutObjectRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) is a string, the Java SDK assumes you want to create an empty object with [`x-amz-website-redirect-location`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) set to the string, which must be an absolute path or URL for the resulting `Location` header.

Comment: This answer helped.
Thanks :)